# How to use WCF task-based asynchronous callback?

Tags: c#, wcf, asynchronous, async-await, callback

I'm pretty new to WCF, so I might be missing something, but what is my question:

I have a WCF service to connect my two apps. One of the app (it is windows service) connects to external server, so I have asynchronous web requests in code. I wanted to do it in following way: I created callback interface with authorization method:

```
public interface ICommunicationServiceCallback
{
    [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
    Task OnAuthorizeAsync(
        string username,
        string password,
        string proxyUrl = null,
        string proxyUsername = null,
        string proxyPassword = null);
}
```

And then I added service reference to my WS code. But instead if `Task OnAuthorizeAsync` method it generates `void OnAuthorize` method, so only way to make it work is having `async void OnAuthorize` method in implementation, which is bad.

 
How can I achieve my goal?

Comment: For how to use asynchronous callbacks in WCF, you can refer to this link, which contains a demo: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5979252/wcf-asynchronous-callback

Comment: @DingPeng I saw this answer, but the problem is that in any case I get `void` returning method after adding service reference to project when I need method that returns `Task`

Comment: The generated client has nothing to do with the server in terms of asynchrony. Which tool are you using to generate the client?

Comment: I'm just adding service reference

Comment: WCF have three asynchronous patterns: the task-based asynchronous pattern, the event-based asynchronous pattern, the IAsyncResult asynchronous pattern. The calling method for each asynchronous mode client is also different, for more information about it, you can refer to this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/synchronous-and-asynchronous-operations